# How to resize action sheet? objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uiactionsheet

Friends i have use one simple action sheet with following code:-

```
popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                        @"Set Calander",
                        @"New Host",
                        @"Approvel",
                        @"Book Session",
                        @"Alter Session",
                        @"Update Post",
                        @"Center View",
                        @"Log Out",
                        nil];
[popup showInView:self.view];
```

It works great when i run this in any iphone simulator but when i try to run this in iPad my actionsheet not shows properly.I have use story board.[image]

Comment: actionsheets are meant to look like that on ipad as far as i know, except you should set the button(or view) from which it is displayed from with `[actionSheet showFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame] inView:self.view animated:YES];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If device is ipad instead of `showinview` use other method such as `tabbar` or `barbuttonitem` or `rectinview`

Reference sample code

```
-(void)actionPhotoShare:(id)sender
    {
    actionSheetShare = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                                  delegate:self 
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                    destructiveButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ActionSheet_Cancel", @"")
                                                         otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ActionSheet_Email", @""),nil];

    if (IS_DEVICE_IPAD) {
        [actionSheetShare showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
    }else {
        [actionSheetShare showInView:self.view];
    }
    }
```

Comment: which value i have to pass for id when i call this method like [self actionPhotoShare:?]

Comment: who ever is calling the method .. it can be self or nil as per your code

Comment: I have use this:-[action_view showFromBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES]; because i am calling action sheet from @selector method , But action sheet is not appear

Comment: Use self 
m getting result 
[self actionPhotoShare:self];